# How do I transfer actions from Adobe Phtotoshop CS 5.1 to the latest version in Creative Cloud?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud, actions

The question title says it all. I'm not a Photoshop guy myself, but my wife got a new computer and we can't transfer her old CS 5.1 to the new one (lost the disc's) so we're looking at the Creative Cloud as a solution.

Comment: Why the down vote? The question seems reasonable to me. If not, please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface may have changed somewhat but loading and saving actions is still the same in Creative Cloud as CS, I believe. Click on the menu icon in the top right corner of the Actions palette and you'll see the commands for loading and saving like this:

[image]